# Facebook Ads API call error: Requiring <page_id> to be admin/dev of app?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, curl

I'm just getting set up with the ads api at my work using cURL. I've been able to successfully authenticate and get data about my ads and I am now trying to create a newsfeed creative for the page. (Specifically one of the new multi product ones, but this example will just be for a basic "object_story_spec" creative).

When I try to post the creative, I get this error:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#272) This Ads API call requires the user to be admin of the application. User <page_id> not admin or developer for application <app_id>.","type":"OAuthException","code":272}}
```

Essentially it seems to be telling me that the *page* needs to be listed as a developer or admin on the app, but I tried this and there is no option to do that. What am I missing here? I am guessing it is some sort of issue with how I generated the access token, which is a page access token generated from the graph api using my own access token that I generated. Any help is tremendously appreciated!

Here is my code (anything in <> was redacted by me):

```
curl https://graph.facebook.com/act_<account>/adcreatives
-F "name=Link Page Post Ad Creative"
-F "object_story_spec={'page_id':<page_id>,'link_data':{'message':'Try it out','link':'http://example.com','picture':'http://example.com/pic.jpg'}}"
-F "access_token=<access_token>"
```

Comment: Why are you using a page access token, did the docs say you should do that? What happens if you try it with your own user access token?

Comment: I can successfully do it with my own token, but the ads that I ultimately want to create are going to be through the page. The reference that I want to use to create the ads is [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/multi-product-ads/v2.2)

Comment: I get the same error from the simple example though. I'm mostly wondering if anybody has had this same error, is it related to permissions?